# Bartender label print preview only displays one label

Tags: printing, label, barcode, bartender

Hi I have setup two labels **using same SQL statement** to retrieve data and have multiple records inserted to the DB.
One label when and id is passed for the print preview it only shows one record. The same id when passed to the other label it previews all the labels.

Generic_old.btw displays **all the 2 labels** in preview,
[image]
[image]

whereas,
Generic.btw only displays **only the 1st label**
[image]
[image]
I cant seem to identify whats wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bartender can see the two records in the database it looks to me you are not using the correct setting for Queried Records. You can find this setting in the printscreen (File ==> print)almost at the bottom under "Record selection". I think your current setting is on "first record only" or "selected" and you should change it to "All".

Comment: It was exactly as you said, thank you. I changed it back to 'All' Now its working perfectly.